# How to send data from one AsyncTask to another AsyncTask?[video system]

Tags: android, audio, video, android-asynctask, mediamuxer

I am trying to capture the audio data and video data separately, and to encode/mux them into a .mp4 file. For audio recording and video encoding both are time-costing job, I open two AsyncTasks for them.

Here is the problem, I need to send the data of audio recording task to the video encoding task. But I didn't find the stuff about communication between AsynTasks.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaCodec API is already async, you submit input data in one method and check for data readiness in another

Comment: Thank you! But it seems that if I want to encode video and audio, I need to creat two instance for MediaCodec. How can they be async?

Comment: Audio encoding is done on CPU (i am not aware about any devices with hw audio encoder) and video encoding is done on GPU, so even here they are not competing. Also, all modern chips have several cores, so they can perform several jobs in parallel. Async means that you submit task to the codec and all jobs are done in internal threads, so your calls are not blocking and you can do some other work in your app, you only need to get the result from codec when internal job is finished = frame encoded for example and codec returns valid result on dequeueOutputBuffer

Comment: Thank you. So in this situation, I can just use the MediaCodec for the encode of audio. Then I provide audio and video to MediaMuxer, as long as I provide them async, the result will be good. Right?

Comment: yes, please consider using sync object to avoid sending audio and video to muxer in the same time. i an not sure if muxer is thread-safe inside

Comment: Thank you. I will two sync task for both audio(capture&encode) and video(encode). Since I put MediaMux at the sync task of vide encode now(The task is excute during the onPriewviewFrame), should I change it to another place? If I don't need to change, how can I provide that audio data to the Muxer?

Comment: muxer should be created as a capturer class(for both video and audio) member i think. write could be called from both onPreview and audioRecorder threads

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any defined communication mechanism between Async Tasks. But one of the Async tasks can write the data it needs to pass to a common object and the other AsyncTask can poll for it at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

you can in the onPostExecute(Result) of the first asynctask launch the second asynctask

Comment: Thank you! @user2689294 I checked that, it seems that it should work, since it can return data to the main thread. But the data is refreshed by frame, do you have any idea how to solve this problem?